# How to use table class of codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Is any trick to add edit/delete link in each row

> Error in code : Cannot use object of type mysqli as array in
>        C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter-3.0.6\application\views\admin.php on line 8

```
<?php 
 $table_property = array('table_open' => '<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="table table-hover">');
  $this->table->set_heading('#Id','Username','Password','Name','Edit','Delete');
  $this->table->set_template($table_property);
  $new=$this->db->query("select * from tbl_admin");

  foreach($new as $row) {
  $links  = anchor('admin/edit/'.$row['User_ID'] ,'Edit');
  $links .= anchor('admin/delete/'.$row['User_ID'] , 'Delete');


$this->table->add_row(
    $row->User_ID,
    $row->Username,
    $row->Password,
    $row->Full_Name,
    $links
    );
}
echo $this->table->generate();
?>
```

Comment: Try this `$links  = anchor('admin/edit/'.$row->User_ID ,'Edit');` and this `$links .= anchor('admin/delete/'.$row->User_ID , 'Delete');` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`query()` doesn't return an array with the objects of desire directly, but an `mysqli_result` object instead; hence you cannot use it as such.

What you probably want to do is

```
while ($row = $new->fetch_assoc()) {
      // ...
}
```